# I don't want to update the value in into database but its getting updated in dot NETCore

Tags: c#, .net, save, task, updating

1. I dont want to update value booking.Price in database (Postgrsql) but it is getting updated.I have following code

   ```
        .........
       public async Task<AppResponse<UpdateBookingCommandResponse>> Handle(UpdateBookingCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
      var booking = await _bookingRepository.GetByGuIdAsync(request.Id);
      booking.Price = request.Price;
      var response = _mapper.Map<UpdateBookingCommandResponse>(booking);
      return Ok(response);
   }
   ...........
   ```
2. Request body

   ```
       public class UpdateBookingCommand : AppRequest<UpdateBookingCommandResponse>, IAuditableRequest
    {
    .......
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Location> PickupLocations { get; set; }
    public decimal OriginalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    .....
   }
   ```
3. Response Body

   ```
   public class UpdateBookingCommandResponse
   {
     .........
    public decimal OriginalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal PaidAmount { get; set; }
    ......
    }
   ```
4. Booking Class

   ```
   public class Booking : BaseEntity
   {
     ......
    public decimal OriginalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceCore { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceGst { get; set; }   
    .......
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want updated the value, use `AsNoTracking`; this function disables the modification's tracking by `dbcontext` and their update when you call `db.saveChange()` like this:

```
db.booking.AsNotTracking().where(b => b.id == id)
```

Also, next time share the function's code to get booking.